# Excel formula or VBA to create simple coversheet calendar from multiple worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have several worksheets that I want to create a simple calendar with. Every month I will be creating a new workbook.  I don't even know where to start....

[image: Sheets]

Detailed operating information is on each worksheet, name of the worksheet is the date and day of week, `4.3m` would be `Monday,April 3rd`.

The `Cover` sheet totals the number of days and total cost, sheets `S` and `l` are only used for formulas in the `Cover` sheet and hidden once month is complete. I would like the `Days` sheet to show a simple chart as a quick reference of the days operated.

[image: Table]

Cell `E3` formula `=IF(COUNT('4.3m'!$AF2),"X","")`, is there a way either with a formula or VBA to have each column pull information from matching worksheet according to date?